# Oracle trigger to update a table when another table insert or update

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables (master-detail) I use to record orders, I need to create a trigger that allows me to update the "TOTAL_GENERAL" field that is in the master table with the sum of subtotals in the "SUBTOTAL" field the detail table that are related to the foreign key "ID_ORDEN" but I get an error with the trigger.

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE  "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN" 
   ("ID_ENCABEZADO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "NUMERO_ORDEN" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FECHA" DATE, 
    "NOMBRE_CLIENTE" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "DIRECCION" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "TOTAL_GENERAL" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "LUGAR_VENTA" VARCHAR2(50), 
     CONSTRAINT "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_ENCABEZADO")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )

CREATE TABLE  "DETALLE_ORDEN" 
   ("ID_DETALLE" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PRODUCTO" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "PRECIO_UNITARIO" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "CANTIDAD" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "SUBTOTAL" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "ID_ENCABEZADO" NUMBER(10,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "DETALLE_ORDEN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_DETALLE")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "DETALLE_ORDEN" ADD CONSTRAINT "DETALLE_ORDEN_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_ENCABEZADO")
      REFERENCES  "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN" ("ID_ENCABEZADO") ENABLE
/
```

trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CALCULAR_TOTAL_GENERAL"
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "DETALLE_ORDEN"
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     V_ID_ENCABEZADO NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN
     SELECT "ID_ENCABEZADO"
     INTO V_ID_ENCABEZADO 
     FROM "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN"
     WHERE "ID_ENCABEZADO" = :NEW."ID_ENCABEZADO";

     UPDATE "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN"
     SET "TOTAL_GENERAL" = (SELECT SUM("SUBTOTAL") FROM "DETALLE_ORDEN"
     WHERE "ID_ENCABEZADO" = V_ID_ENCABEZADO)
     WHERE "ID_ENCABEZADO" = V_ID_ENCABEZADO;
END;
```

This is the error message I get when I insert or update the table "DETALLE_ORDEN":

```
1 error has occurred
ORA-04091: table CARLOSM.DETALLE_ORDEN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it 
ORA-06512: at "CARLOSM.CALCULAR_TOTAL_GENERAL", line 9 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CARLOSM.CALCULAR_TOTAL_GENERAL'
```

Comment: Try googling ORA-04091 and understand mutating tables and how to get rid of this error. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use triggers for this kind of logic (for that matter, don't use triggers ever; there's almost always a better way).  Also, avoid storing redundant information in base tables whenever possible.

Far better design, with minimal impact to existing code is to 
1) rename table "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN" (i.e. to "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN_TAB") and 2)  disable/drop "TOTAL_GENERAL" field, and then 3) create a view with original name "ENCABEZADO_ORDEN" as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ENCABEZADO_ORDEN AS 
SELECT O.*, (SELECT SUM(D.SUBTOTAL) FROM DETALLE_ORDEN D 
           WHERE D.ID_ENCABEZADO = O.ID_ENCABEZADO) TOTAL_GENERAL 
FROM ENCABEZADO_ORDEN_TAB O;
```

This will ensure TOTAL_GENERAL is always correct (in fact, any efforts to set it directly to some other value via update of ENCABEZADO_ORDEN will result in immediate syntax error).

If performance is an issue (i.e. users frequently query TOTAL_GENERAL field in ENCABEZADO_ORDEN table for orders with large numbers of detail records in DETALLE_ORDEN, causing Oracle to repeatedly fetch&sum multitudes of SUBTOTALS) then use a materialized view instead of a basic view.